# va_arg will overflow in clang and apple mac os x?

Tags: c++

```
#include <cstdarg>
#include <iostream>

void print(const size_t n, ...) {
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, n);
  for (size_t i = 0; i< n; ++i ) {
    auto v = va_arg(args, uint64_t);
    std::cout<< v << std::endl;
  }
  va_end(args);
  return;
}

int main() {
  print(6, 1,2,3,4,5,6);
  //print(5, 1,2,3,4,5);
  return 0;
};
```

then I got the output:

 ~/private/code/cpp/trial/ ./a.out
1
2
3
4
5
140728898420742

Comment: why do you assume that the type is uint64_t?

Comment: Change your loop to `for (size_t i = 0; i< n; i++ )`

Comment: @VictorGubin ++i / i++ is same. except u want to get the value of (++i)

Comment: @OznOg I add static_cast<uint64_t> for every input. and it got fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `print` function assumes that arguments are passed as `uint64_t`. When you invoke the function, you however specify the values as integer literals, so the compiler will choose to pass them as `int`.

If you pass the numbers as `1ULL`, `2ULL` etc. then things should work. Or assume that the values are of type `int` in function `print`. Note that this use of `va_arg`. The compiler will not warn about type mismatches and you can get pretty weird behavior. For example if by accident you pass a floating point value like 1.5.

Since you are using C++, variadic templates might be better suited to your case.